# bibliographystyle agsm uses deprecated command \bf

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

I am using `natbib` with `agsm` (harvard citation style), which apparently uses the deprecated `\bf` command. Upon compiling, I receive a hundred warnings. Does this mean that `agsm` is itself deprecated? If so, how do I get exactly the same layout with a more recent style?

Comment: @MERose The command `\bf` was deprecated twenty years ago. Unfortunately, people continue to use it. Markus Kohm, in his KOMA classes, decided to add the warning (it's a good thing, in my opinion), but he can do nothing with software from third parties.

Comment: @egreg: the old meaning of \bf is deprected, but the definition in the article class imho maps the command to something sensible. People like short commands, and  `\bf` has compared to `\bfseries` the advantage to be usable in math too. Imho Markus should either drop the command -- nobody can force him to provide it -- or use the article definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}` to your document to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: in my opinion the fact that there is such a work-around only stresses how disputable is the decision of Markus to issue all these harassing warnings. Why didn't the class simply apply itself the redefinition you advocate ?

Comment: @jfbu This is not a *re*definition, but the standard definition from article.cls. It is KOMA that uses another definition. I don't understand all the warnings either. Beside filling the log file, it broke tex4ht. Imho Markus should either remove the commands completely or simply use the standard definition.